# Launch a file through iPhone-Programming

Tags: ios4

I have developed an application where i can download any kind of file from url. Myquestion is that is there any way to launch that file in iPhone using existing application or native apps.My downloaded file is in application directory.Any kind of help is appreciable Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```